# Developer option "Do not keep activites" gets stuck

Tags: samsung

I'm rocking a Samsung Galaxy S6, 5.1.1, build number LMY47X.*

When turning on the "Do not keep activities" developer option, the toggle turns green.  It is toggled back off as soon as I navigate away from the developer options screen, and my testing shows that it is indeed off.

A workaround was to toggle it on, then lock the phone.  After unlocking it, the toggle stays on and activities are not kept.  The opposite problem is then present: it won't turn off.  The workaround above does not seem to work in this case (I wonder if it was a fluke).

Some googling brings up a few instances of people with S6's and Note 5's with a similar problem, and a few conspiracy theories around samsung intentionally leaving it locked on, but nothing concrete about how to solve this.

Is this a bug, a dirty Samsung battery-saver hack job, or am I alone in experiencing this?

Comment: Is it a rooted phone?

Comment: No, it is a stock phone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mystery solved!

Clicking the toggle does nothing.  Clicking the text itself works, though.  It looks like Samsung's devs have a click listener on the list item, but not the toggle switch itself.

Comment: Same for Galaxy S7 Edge, bug reported here: http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=298733&startId=zzzzz~

Answer (score 0):

I have a galaxy prime core phone that I upgraded to s8 and tried the smart switch. Kept getting that same message with the same results. What I did was toggle the button off for ALL developer options at the very top of the screen. It worked. Transferring media as I am writing this. One note though, this is an extremely slow process, might want to try just transferring via a computer